# "Google Drive WP Media" WordPress Plugin gives error

Tags: php, wordpress, google-drive-api, http-status-code-404, image-uploading

I have a WordPress website(Latest Version), in which I've used [Google Drive WP Media](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-drive-wp-media/) plugin. Plugin working fine thanks, guys. But this plugin gives an error which is not showing to the normal person, the error is:

> when we hit the URL in the browser, an image is showing but when we hit the same URL with the help of curl, it gives the **404** error.

[image]

Now, what can i do?? do you guys have any solutions for this problem?
Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is sorted out… add only one line and the problem is resolved.

open “**google-drive-wp-media.php**” file and add the following line after this line(**line no 2661**):

> Before:

```
@header (‘Cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000’);
```

> After:

```
@header(‘HTTP/1.1 200 OK’);
@header (‘Cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000’);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this suggested action for [`404` errors](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#404_file_not_found_fileid):

> Report to users that they do not have read access to the file or that the file does not exist. Tell them that they should ask the owner for permission to the file.

This [beginner's guide](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-connect-google-drive-to-your-wordpress-media-library/) might also help.

Comment: it's not the solution if I'll disable the plugin, it means current images not showing.